# Added 2nd monitor, caused mouse and keyboard not to work and more

Tags: 14.04, ati, keyboard, multiple-monitors, mouse

So I have a Radeon 9800 with 2Gb video RAM, Intel i7 4th gen, 32Gb RAM Dell XPS 8700 chassis running Ubuntu 14.04.

I've had 2 monitors on my desk as I switched from my old PC and today I finally disconnect the old PC and moved the monitor cable to the 2nd port of the ATI Radeon 9800 - it has 2 DVI out ports, 2 display ports, and a HDMI and says only 2 of the 5 can be used at once.

So I've had 1 monitor working well for a while - when I connect the 2nd I got nothing on the 2nd screen.  So I tried rebooting, figured not a bad idea, and it came back up without all my auto-start programs on the screen and my mouse and keyboard not working - i.e. won't even light up the LED on mouse or when I press caps lock on the PC.

I tried VNC to access from another PC and I see my normal desktop with all the normal programs had loaded - I look back at the original monitor and it's viewing a different desktop...  Like when you press Ctrl+Alt+F1 or F2, etc. and see different desktop workspaces.   But from VNC, I see my "native" one I've always been used to.  (the new monitor was still blank screen).

So I unplugged the 2nd monitor that didn't work, and rebooted, and now it's back to working but with only one monitor.

What's happening?  How can it get the 2nd monitor to work without disabling my interface devices?

Thanks in advance,
-d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: Turns out that only one of the 2 DVI ports on the card work with a DVI to VGA adapter for analog monitors—the 2nd DVI is DVI only.

I am using 2 analog monitors so I need to swap one out to true digital DVI.